# Solve promise show only array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, promise

I have been able to resolve the promise that returned me

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(7)
```

But this time I had the problem when extracting the variable, in this case it turned out, the reason I want to extract it is to store it in a react useState.

This is the code

```
 const fsdasfda = db
    .collection("socios")
    .where("activity", "==", "true")
    .orderBy("num")
    .get()
    .then(function (query) {
      const array = [];
      query.forEach(function (doc) {
        const data = doc.data();
        array.push(data);
      });
      return array;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });

  console.log(fsdasfda);
```

const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(HERE);

console.log (result); it returns the data as I want to pass to the use state.
console.log (fsdasfda); the promise returns

As I mentioned earlier I want to pass the RESULT value to the useState

I try this but it still appears as a promise.

fsdasfda.then((data) => console.log(data));

Comment: The `docs` property needs to be accessed in order to get the full list of documents from the query. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs

Comment: fsdasfda.then(data => console.log(data)); this will help you.

Comment: I want to pass to useState [] not setState const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(HERE) but it is a initial state

Comment: I believe the only way you can pass the resolved value to `useState()` is to have its parent component performs the async task and pass the result to it as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this log as you are logging promise, add await to your DB query [this code snippet should be inside an async function] and then use fsdasfda.then(data => updateState(data));

```
const fsdasfda = await db // added await
.collection("socios")
.where("activity", "==", "true")
.orderBy("num")
.get()
.then(function (query) {
  const array = [];
  query.forEach(function (doc) {
    const data = doc.data();
    array.push(data);
  });
  return array;
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
fsdasfda.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  setUnidades(data); // updating state and logging result data.
});
```

Check this should work.

Comment: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: read the first statement it's already written in square brackets []

Comment: I want to pass to useState [] not setState
const [unidades, setUnidades] = useState(HERE)
but it is a initial state

Comment: I was talking about [this code snippet should be inside an async function]